# How can i test the existence of a function in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Is there a way to test the existence of a function or method in Dart without trying to call it and catch a NoSuchMethodError error?
I am looking for something like

```
if (exists("func_name")){...}
```

to test whether a function named`func_name`exists.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with [mirrors API](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_mirrors.html) :

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Test {
  method1() => "hello";
}

main() {
  print(existsFunction("main")); // true
  print(existsFunction("main1")); // false
  print(existsMethodOnObject(new Test(), "method1")); // true
  print(existsMethodOnObject(new Test(), "method2")); // false
}

bool existsFunction(String functionName) => currentMirrorSystem().isolate
    .rootLibrary.functions.containsKey(functionName);

bool existsMethodOnObject(Object o, String method) => reflect(o).type.methods
    .containsKey(method);
```

`existsFunction` only tests if a function with `functionName` exists in the current library. Thus with functions available by `import` statement `existsFunction` will return `false`.